# Infopath 2010 offline connection

Tags: sharepoint-2010, offline, infopath

I have an infopath form template with code customizations, which involves 2 sharepoint lists. The form template works fine with online connections which uses WCF 's UpdateListItems process.

My question is  how do I make it work offline? As WCF service updates only when the form is online. When the form template goes offline, how do I update the data to sharepoint workspace? I understand I need to use the Sharepoint Workspace to store the offline data before it is transferred when online connnectivity is resumed.

Thanks and Regards